# Updating static text in android programatically

Tags: android

first stop I read that you can't change the strings.xml on runtime, but I'm looking for a way to create another xml file example objects.xml and restart the app so by the next restart it sees the objects.xml as a resource.

Well I can also accept suggestion that does not include xml files. Though as much as possible I don't want to use database because of the performance issue but it may be my last choice depending on the answers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the contents of the APK at runtime. There are multiple ways to store data on Android, as described in [Storage Options](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). In your case, I think [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) would be a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And my best option would be my last choice which is saving it to the database well I guess I'll just limit the number of static label that can be change using this feature.